# «Алёнка»-шоколадка

Tags: орфография

Если второе слово — приложение, то понятно, как писать.

> Шоколадка «Алёнка».

А если оно первое, то надо писать его наподобие *клюква-ягода*, но в кавычках. Так?

> «Алёнка»-шоколадка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать так:

*Есть не только **«Алёнка»-шоколадка,** но и   [другие сладости](https://yandex.ru/products/search?text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%C2%AB%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%C2%BB&src=web_tg)  бренда «Алёнка»: **печенье, конфеты.***